# Require assistance with failed to open stream: Permission denied in

Tags: permissions, wordpress

I have set up (actually migrated) wordpress on ubuntu 10.04 with apache2 and everything works great. However, I'm getting the following error when using a plugin to upload files to the server:

> [Wed Jun 06 13:12:29 2012] [error] [client xx.xxx.xxx.xxx] PHP
>   Warning: 
>   fopen(/home/user/public/website.com/public/wp-content/plugins/cforms/abspath.php):
>   failed to open stream: Permission denied in
>   /home/user/public/website.com/public/wp-content/plugins/cforms/lib_functions.php
>   on line 164, referer:
>   http://website.com/wp-admin/plugins.php?deactivate=true&plugin_status=all&paged=1&s=

I've taken a bit too much on I think. I'm not a developer at all, but I thought it would be fun to try and set myself up with a Linode VPS.

I suspect that there is some sort of permissions problem. www-data is my php user. Could it be that www-data is lacking permissions? And how do I go about troubleshooting this?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give 755 permissions to the `/home/user/public/website.com/public/` folder, subfolders and all files.

Comment: I thought I had. Is there a command that I can use to check this?

Comment: I typed this just now: sudo chmod -R 755 /home/user/public/website.com/public/

Of course changing user and website.com with my own.

Still getting error.

Comment: Reapply with `sudo chmod -R 755 /home/user/public/website.com/public/`

Comment: Thanks jasmines. I'm not sure what you mean "Reapply"? Shouldn't typing the command once be sufficient? Please be patient with me because I'm new to linux.

Comment: Yes, type it in a terminal.

Comment: Sorry! Yes, I think this has fixed that error in fact.
Thank you very much!